# FilesBrowse() function takes all selected files as one item

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm working on a GUI using PySimpleGUI, and I want user to browse multiple files, put each of them in an array, and get the length of the array.

But FilesBrowse() taking all files as one object and `len(posts)` code giving the output of "1", even If I choose 10 files.

How to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

global posts

posts = []

layouts =  [[sg.Text("Browse the XLSX file: "), sg.FilesBrowse(key=0)],
           [sg.Button('Start The Process')], [[sg.Button('Exit')]]]

window = sg.Window("Title", layouts)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    posts.append(values[0])
    x = len(posts)
    print(x)
```

Comment: every variable created outside function is already `global` and you don't need `global post`. We use `global` inside function to inform it that we want to assign to external/global variable instead of creating local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should see what you get `print(values[0])` - and you should see that it uses `;` between names - so you can split it with `split(';')`

```
posts = values[0].split(';')
```

or if you want to extend existing list then use `+=` (instead of `append()`)

```
posts += values[0].split(';')
```

---

Full working code

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

posts = []  # it is global variable and it doesn't need `global posts`

layouts =  [
    [sg.Text("Browse the XLSX file: "), sg.FilesBrowse(key=0)],
    [sg.Button('Start The Process')],
    [sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layouts)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

# --- after loop ---

if values[0]: # check if files were selected
    posts += values[0].split(';')

print('len:', len(posts))
print('posts:', posts)
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems on some systems `if` has to be inside `while`

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    if values[0]: # check if files were selected
        posts += values[0].split(';')

    print('len:', len(posts))
    print('posts:', posts)
```

Comment: I put if statement to while loop, and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: on my Linux I have to use `if` outside `while` - it never works inside `while`. It seems it never send information when I close `FilesBrowse` but only when I close window.

Comment: I don't know, when I used if out of while, It gave me an error. So I put it in, and It worked. Interesting though. For future people, If you face with an error when you run @furas 's code, try putting if statement inside while.

Comment: I added this information to answer - it will be bette visible.

Answer (score 0):

You may get problem if you click on close button of window.
It is caused by the value of `values` returned from `window.read()`, most of time, it will be `None`, so you cannot get `values[0]`, then

```py
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

To update other element, `sg.Filesbrowse` return `str` and use `sg.BROWSE_FILES_DELIMITER`, or `';'`, as delimiter. So you can get a list of files by using method `str.split(';')`. Of course, you can call `sg.popup_get_file` in event loop, it may return `str` or list of `str` which depend on option `multiple_files`.

Demo code here

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(element_padding=(3, 3))

posts = []

layouts =  [
    [sg.Text("Browse the XLSX file: ")],
    [sg.Input(key='-INPUT-'), sg.FilesBrowse(file_types=(("xlsx Files", "*.xlsx"), ("ALL Files", "*.*")))],
    [sg.Button('Add'), sg.Button('Exit')],
    [sg.Multiline(size=(80, 25), key='-MULTILINE-')],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layouts, finalize=True)
multiline = window['-MULTILINE-']
window['-INPUT-'].expand(expand_x=True)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Add':
        path = values['-INPUT-']
        if path:
            posts += path.split(";")
        multiline.print(f'len: {len(posts)}')
        multiline.print(f'posts: {posts}')

window.close()
```